# Call dialogue box for OData feed authentication

Tags: excel, vba, authentication, powerquery, excel-2013

I have an Excel workbook that pulls fact tables from Dataverse for Teams via Power Query. This workbook is shared across our organization. The users are (for the most part) technically naive. So when a query fails to refresh due to lack of authentication, I need the authentication dialogue box to automatically pop up.
[image: OData authentication dialogue]

I'd like to write a Workbook_Open sub to check if the user is signed in to a particular OData connection. If they are not, I'd like to call the dialogue (pictured above) so that they can sign in before it causes them any issues.

My problem is, I can't find any documentation showing which object(s) and methods to use. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You might call this Sub as the application will use the users default browser to establish a new window:

```
Sub sbVBA_To_Open_Website_URL_FollowHypderlink()
    Dim strURL As String
    strURL = "https.//org16c3abbe.crm.dynamics.com/"
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink (strURL) 
End Sub
```